# Python Mouse X and Y position

Tags: python

Can I find the mouse x/y coordinate with a built in variable? If so, what is that variable called? I also don't want to have the mouse left click clicked to find the position.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built in variable that gives you the mouse cursor position.

The [`PyAutoGUI`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package provides that functionality. Install it with `pip install pyautogui`.

```py
import pyautogui

x, y = pyautogui.position()

print(x)
print(y)
```

Here my mouse cursor was near the top left of my screen:

```
50
75
```